# Linq to ad, disconnectedcontext exception fired

Tags: c#, linq, active-directory

I have an exception which is fired when I test some code of mine using the library [Linq to AD](http://linqtoad.codeplex.com/).

I am using a repository with this function :

```
 public UserAD GetUser(string username) 
        {
            UserAD user = null;
            using (Root = CreateDirectoryEntry())
            {
                var users = new DirectorySource<UserAD>(Root, SearchScope.Subtree);

                user = users.Where(x => x.AccountName == username)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .SingleOrDefault();             //not supported in LDAP; alternative in-memory SingleOrDefault

            }
            return user;
        }
```

This works fine when I call it directly:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void RepositoryUtenteAD_GetUser()
        {
            UserAD user = repositoryAD.GetUser("TestAD_OK");

            Assert.AreEqual("blablabla", user.DistinguishedName);

            Assert.IsFalse(user.AccountDisabled);
        }
```

But I may use another method which will call GetUser:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void RepositoryUtenteAD_AutenticazioneUtente_Authentication()
        {
            IAutenticazione auth = repositoryAD.AutenticazioneUtente("TestAD_OK", "TestAD_OK");
            Assert.IsTrue(auth.IsAuthenticated);
        }
```

and the Authentication method is as follows (cleared of meaning and details, the error remaining there) :

```
public IAutenticazione AutenticazioneUtente(string username, string password)
        {
            bool IsWhyNotAuthentifiedFound = false;
            IAutenticazione authenticazione = new Autenticazione();

            UserAD user = GetUser(username);
            return authenticazione;
}
```

The test is running fine, the assert is giving me the good value, but after the Cleanup of my test I have a disconnectedcontext exception fired. I assume it comes from the Interop.Adsi dll I use.

In GetUser(username) Should I copy everything I have in my UserAD to make a clone and so be clear off context...? Or is there a more clever way to approach?

Thanks for your reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution even if it is a strange one. The bug only happens when running the test in debug mode, if i choose run instead of debug, everything is fine.

That close the chapter. Thanks for your reading.